# Search and paste data from sheet 2 to sheet 1 form

Tags: excel, vba

I have Sheet1 which is a form with fields where we enter data to be fed in the database (Sheet2).

Ideally, here's what I want it to do:

I want to search a field/record using the form contents in Sheet1, then search for that term on Sheet2. If it doesn't exist on Sheet2, give me a pop up message saying data doesn't exist.

If it does exist in Column A on Sheet2, then select the cell to the right of the result (Column B). Then paste that cell's contents in relevant fields on Sheet1
Then continue until all of the fields on Sheet1 has been searched for on Sheet2.

Here's the code I've been using. It only works for about 5 lines before it comes up with an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I really don't want the MsgBox to pop up at all.

```
Sub abc()

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    Dim MyString As String
    MyString = ActiveCell
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Set RangeObj = Cells.Find(What:=MyString, After:=ActiveCell, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If RangeObj Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Not Found" Else: RangeObj.Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -1).Select
Loop
End Sub
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right path.. just a few amendments to how you were copying the data.

```
Option Explicit
Sub sheet2_lookup()
    Dim strVal As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, RangeObj As Range
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

    Cells(1, 1).Activate '' amend this to your starting cell
    While ActiveCell.Value2 <> ""
        strVal = ActiveCell.Value2
        Set RangeObj = ws2.Columns("A").Find(What:=strVal, After:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues)
        If RangeObj Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Not Found"
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = RangeObj.Offset(0, 1).Value2
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Wend
End Sub
```

Let me know how it goes.